# How do you find the x-intercepts of a quadratics -1 + 3 x - x^3

Tags: equation-solving

How do I find the intercept of -1 + 3 x - x^3? when I use solve it gives me imaginary numbers and 'Reals' doesn't work either but when I plot it there is an x intercept

Comment: `when I use solve it gives me imaginary numbers`  Well, on my computer:  `eq = -1 + 3 x - x^3 == 0;
Solve[eq, x] // N` gives `{{x -> -1.87939}, {x -> 0.347296}, {x -> 1.53209}}`. You should really show what you did. Not say I did this and that, but show the code.

Comment: In fact `FullSimplify@Solve[-1+3x-x^3==0]` captures (for me on v11) one of the three real roots, `2 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]`. I don't know how to get the other two ($2\cos(4\pi/9)$ and $2\cos(8\pi/9)$).

Comment: Why "quadratics"?

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = -1 + 3 x - x^3 == 0;
```

To avoid [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions in the result, use the option `Cubics -> True`. Then use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to simplify the results.

```
sol = Solve[eq, x, Cubics -> True] // ComplexExpand

(* {{x -> Cos[π/9] + Sqrt[3] Sin[π/9]}, {x -> 
   Cos[π/9] - Sqrt[3] Sin[π/9]}, {x -> -2 Cos[π/9]}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
eq /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(* {{x -> 1.53209}, {x -> 0.347296}, {x -> -1.87939}} *)
```

Comment: `//ComplexExpand` works in version 11 also without `Cubics -> True`